# print strings after the "@" character is seen

Tags: python

So I've got this problematic string within a example list:

```
pM = ['sam DM @carl hello friends do you know each other, @james?']
```

I need a way to print both names after the "@" sign so far I can only come up with how to print one IE:

```
def mentioned():
    for s in pM:
        if "@" in s:
            userName = s.split()
            single = (userName[3])
            data.append(single)
        else:
            None
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex:

```
import re
pM = ["sam DM @carl hello friends do you know each other", "@james?"]
for i in pM:
    print(re.findall("\@[a-z]+", i)[0])
```

**Output:**

```
@carl
@james
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
import re
pM = ['sam DM @carl hello friends do you know each other, @james?']
list1 = pM[0].split(' ')
x = [ele for ele in list1 if re.split('@', ele) and '@' in ele]           # This will filter the strings with '@' in it
for name in x:
    print(re.split('@', name)[1])         # This prints only the names 'carl', 'james'
```

Output:

```
['@carl', '@james?']
carl
james
```

If you don't want to use `import re` just use the below code:

```
 for ele in pM[0].split():
    if '@' in ele or '?' in ele:
        print(ele.strip('@?'))
```

Output:

```
carl
james
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without importing re?

Comment: Regex (regular expressions) is the best way to do what you want, is there any reason you can't import the regex library?

Comment: A very irritating requirement is to not use imports

Comment: @Lara: I have updated the answer with and without using the 'import re'. Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: how can you account for removing all "?" and "@" when printing?

Comment: @Lara: When we are using the `strip()` we can remove that `@` and `?`

Comment: @Lara: Did you got the required answer ?